# Problem with defining a hole filing function (according to mathematical definition) in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, user-defined-functions

I'm new to python, so please consider that :)
I was trying to **fill** the **holes** of a **binary** image after applying "closing" on it **without** using any **built-in functions**. I wanted to do something like this (down below) on my Head Ct picture.
[continously erosion with a structuring element(+) (similar to the equation on it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhqhK.jpg) 
so I wrote this code, but I still have a problem with the initial point.

```
def holefiling(img,B):
    initial= np.zeros_like(img)
    imginv = cv.bitwise_not(img)
    i=np.random.choice(img.shape[0])
    j=np.random.choice(img.shape[1])
    while img[i,j]!=np.max(img):#FINDING A WHITE HOLE WITH THE brightest intensities
        i=np.random.choice(img.shape[0])
        j=np.random.choice(img.shape[1])
    
    initial[i,j]=imginv[i,j]
    #initial=cv.bitwise_not(initial)#?
    for k in (0,10000):#10000 times of doing this algoryithm might solve all of it
        erosion = cv.erode(initial,B,iterations = 1) #X_k erosion with structuring element B
        X_k=initial & erosion
        initial=X_k
    Output=X_k | img
    return Output

kernel=cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))# defining a 3*3 cross(+) structure
Holefilled=holefiling(closing,kernel)

#showing the result
plt.figure()
plt.suptitle('fingerprint.tif')

plt.subplot(131)
plt.title(r'${Original_{img}}$')
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(img))
plt.axis(False)

plt.subplot(132)
plt.title(r'${closing}$')
plt.imshow(closing, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(closing))
plt.axis(False)

plt.subplot(133)
plt.title(r'${Holefilled}$')
plt.imshow(Holefilled, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(Holefilled))
plt.axis(False)
```

The result doesn't show any changes to the picture, and I got confused about why it happened. (In fact, I thought that the initial point must be in the brightest area, and also, there must be a change by increasing its iteration while nothing happened .) here you can see the result:
[zooming on the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bepB.png)

I think the problem might be related to one of these.
1.the initial point must be somewhere in between the holes, but I don't know how :|
2.the process of replacing X_k in the code has a little bit problem
3.structuring element (cross +) should be something else(the chances of this option is way too low :D )
so, please everyone who could help me do it, thank you so super much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Initial Point Of a Holfilling Process**

I have found an answer to my question, but to those, it may be their question too. I wouldn't delete my question and want to add my answer.
I solved the **Problem of Finding Initial** you may want to know how? so I decided to find a hole point that has a zero value while the summation of the points of 4 lines around it has a value similar to be filled lines. (if you want to fill the white holes inside of a black area, you should find a point that has a 1 value while summation of the points of four lines around it is zero)
here is my code:

```
def holefiling(img,B):
img1 = np.array(img)  
#imginv
thresh = 0/5
binarr = np.where(img1>thresh, 0, 1)# if i wrote: np.where(img>thresh, 1,0) the color would be reversed
# Covert numpy array back to image 
binimg = np.asmatrix(binarr)
#binimg1  = cv.threshold(img, thresh, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
imginv=binimg.astype('uint8')  

hf=13 #depends on situation of the hole
#finding an initial point:
#1.defining a black initial
initial= np.zeros_like(img)

#finding a white pixel inside a black area:
#separating each pixel of the image but not around the edges: [hf:img.shape[0]-hf]
for i in range(0+hf,img.shape[0]-hf):
    for j in range(0+hf,img.shape[1]-hf):
        #print(np.sum(img[i-hf:i+hf,j+hf]))
        #print(img[78,236])
        #checking if the i,j pixel is black while around it has white lines according to the equations of these lines below and vice-versa
        if np.sum(img[i-hf:i+hf,j-hf])>=hf+hf/2 and np.sum(img[i-hf:i+hf,j+hf])>=hf+hf/2 and np.sum(img[i-hf,j-hf:j+hf])>=1/2 and np.sum(img[i+hf,j-hf:j+hf])>=1/2 and img[i,j]==0:
            #finally the initial point for the holefiling process
            """ print(img[i,j])
            print(img[j,i]) """
            i_init=i
            j_init=j
            print(i_init,j_init)
            initial[i_init,j_init]=imginv[i_init,j_init]

        #print(i_init,j_init)
        """ elif np.sum(img[i-hf:i+hf,j-hf])>=hf and np.sum(img[i-hf:i+hf,j+hf])>=hf and np.sum(img[i-hf,j-hf:j+hf])>=hf and np.sum(img[i+hf,j-hf:j+hf])>=hf and img[i,j]==0:
            print(i,j)
            i_init=i
            j_init=j
            initial[i_init,j_init]=img[i_init,j_init] """
print(img[i_init,j_init])
#initial[i_init,j_init]=imginv[i_init,j_init]
plt.figure()
plt.title(r'${InitialPoints}$')
plt.imshow(initial, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(initial))
plt.axis(False)
plt.show()        
#initial[i_init,j_init]=img[i_init,j_init]
for k in range(100):#ten times of doing this algorithym might solve all of it
    dialation=cv.dilate(initial,B,iterations=1)
    X_k=imginv & dialation #img | dialation
    
    #if you want to check the code and wanna know how it works in each iteration, simply run this part down below
    """ plt.figure
    plt.subplot(144)
    plt.imshow(X_k, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(initial))
    plt.axis(False)
    plt.subplot(141)
    plt.imshow(initial, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(initial))
    plt.axis(False)
    plt.subplot(142)
    plt.imshow(dialation, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(dialation))
    plt.axis(False)
    plt.subplot(143)
    plt.imshow(imginv, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(initial))
    plt.axis(False)
    plt.show() """
    initial=X_k

#complementing X_k in order to have both images in complent mode
""" binarrinv = np.where(X_k>0, 0, 1)# if i wrote: np.where(img>thresh, 1,0) the color would be reversed
# Covert numpy array back to image 
binimginv = np.asmatrix(binarrinv)
imgOut=binimginv.astype('uint8')#imgOut """
Output=(X_k | img)# since the img and imgout are the complement of what we had in the slides so if we use intersection between two complements is equal to the union of two original images
return Output`
```

so to check how does it work, I run this code below:

```
img= cv.imread('HeadCT.tif',0)
img = np.array(img)  
# Put threshold to 100 according to question to make it binary
thresh = 100
binarr = np.where(img>thresh, 1, 0)
# Covert numpy array back to image 
binimg = np.asmatrix(binarr)
binimg1=binimg.astype('uint8')
kernel=cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(20,20))# defining a 20*20 ELLIPSE structure
closing = cv.morphologyEx(binimg1, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)# closing with Kernel
kernel1=cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))# defining a 3*3 ellipse structure
#testing my function

Holefilled1=holefiling(closing,kernel1)#for one of the holes
plt.figure()
plt.suptitle('HeadCT.tif')

plt.subplot(131)
plt.title(r'${Original_{img}}$')
plt.imshow(binimg1, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(binimg1))
plt.axis(False)

plt.subplot(132)
plt.title(r'${closing_{on_{original img}}}$')
plt.imshow(closing, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(closing))
plt.axis(False)

plt.subplot(133)
plt.title(r'${Holefilled_{after_{closing}}}$')
plt.imshow(Holefilled1, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(Holefilled1))
plt.axis(False)

plt.show()
```

here is the input image[HeadCt.tif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4ecq.png)
and here is the output of it[Results of hole-filling after closing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFOoz.png)
You can use this result also for finding the boundaries of an object.
I hope you enjoyed it as much as I did. :)